# Selenium Getting Stale exception when navigating to next page using loop

Tags: java, selenium

After listing all countries and language, I want to navigate to next page. Below are the code that I am using for the same. With this code I get the first country data and after this i am getting Stale exception.

```
    int indexGroupRow = 0;  
    for (WebElement rowElement:listRows) 
    {
      if (rowElement.getAttribute("class").contains("dxgvGroupRow") 
          && rowElement.getAttribute("id").contains("Content_gvCountries_DXGroupRowExp"+indexGroupRow))
      {
           String t = rowElement.getText();
           System.out.println("Country: "+t);
      }
      if (rowElement.getAttribute("class").contains("dxgvDataRow") 
          && rowElement.getAttribute("id").contains("Content_gvCountries_DXDataRow"+indexGroupRow))
      {
           String t1 = rowElement.getText();
           System.out.println("Available Language: " + t1);
           List<WebElement> linkElement = rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td[position()>1]"));
           for (WebElement er: linkElement)
           {
               er.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Content_gvCountries_cell" 
                   + indexGroupRow 
                   + "_2_lnkSelectCountry_" 
                   + indexGroupRow + "']")).click();
           }
      }
      indexGroupRow++;
   }
```

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
>   reference: element is not attached to the page document   (Session
>   info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243
>   (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html Build
>   info: version: '2.53.1', revision:
>   'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09' System info: host: 'WINJITLAPTOP96', ip: '192.168.224.1',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_67' Session ID: adf74ce205fd64d8b3d5c5064781985b
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   browserName=chrome,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\deepakv\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11036_1170},
>   rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=52.0.2743.116,
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:179)
>     at LoginTest.testLogin(LoginTest.java:61) Disconnected from the
>   target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:23563', transport: 'socket'

Answer (score 1):

```
for (WebElement er: linkElement)
       {
           er.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Content_gvCountries_cell" + indexGroupRow + "_2_lnkSelectCountry_" + indexGroupRow + "']")).click();
       }
```

After first click you lose another links, so driver can't click on second element from linkElement list(because it belongs to previous page).
You need to find link to next page after each click